# Classic ASP reading XML values

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I'm trying to define the driving distance between 2 points using the google maps api. It returns an XML which I load into a XMLDOM object. However I can't seem to find anywhere how I can get the value of a child within a child within a child ... I have read the Microsoft tutorial but it doesn't show how to retreive values from the XML.

An example XML is:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>Gentsesteenweg 5, 9200 Dendermonde, België</origin_address>
<destination_address>Veerstraat 39, 9200 Dendermonde, België</destination_address>
<row>
    <element>
        <status>OK</status>
        <duration>
            <value>117</value>
            <text>2 min.</text>
        </duration>
        <distance>
            <value>1061</value>
            <text>1,1 km</text>
        </distance>
    </element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

The part of my code is:

```
Set XmlObj = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
strURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & dblFromLatitude & "+" & dblFromLongitude & "&destinations=" & dblToLatitude & "+" & dblToLongitude & "&mode=driving&language=" & strLanguage & "&sensor=false"
'DebugFile strURL
XmlObj.Open "POST", strURL, false
XmlObj.send      
strResponse = XmlObj.responseText
Set XmlObj = Nothing


Set xmlLongLat = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlLongLat.async=false
xmlLongLat.loadXML(strResponse)

If Not xmlLongLat.GetElementsByTagName("DistanceMatrixResponse")(0).ChildNodes(0).GetElementsByTagName("row")(0).ChildNodes(0).GetElementsByTagName("element")(0).ChildNodes(0).GetElementsByTagName("distance")(0).ChildNodes(0) Is Nothing Then

    dblDrivingDistance = Round(CDbl(Nz(xxmlLongLat.GetElementsByTagName("DistanceMatrixResponse")(0).ChildNodes(0).GetElementsByTagName("row")(0).ChildNodes(0).GetElementsByTagName("element")(0).ChildNodes(0).GetElementsByTagName("distance")(0).ChildNodes(0).NodeValue, 0))/1000,2)
Else 'xmlLongLat.GetElementsByTagName("element")(0) Is Nothing Then
    dblDrivingDistance = 0
    DebugFile "fgfzefzef"
End If 'xmlLongLat.GetElementsByTagName("element")(0) Is Nothing Then

Set xmlLongLat = Nothing
```

I want to get the "value" of "distance" but I just don't seem to succeed despite having tried about everything

Comment: Have you already tried the "step-by-step"-method? Why don't you store the response into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/row/elelemnt/distance/value").innerText
```

*or similar* - play with the XPath

Comment: Adding "xmlLongLat.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

 Set node = xmlLongLat.selectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/value")
 dblDrivingDistance = Nz(node.text,0)" after the loadXML returns a "Object required: 'node'" error on the last line. looks like the XML is never loaded or something

Comment: I was trying to query the google maps driving distance api but it appears I had used all of my daily queries, which is why it didn't work. Should be "node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/elelemnt/distance/value").text" to be correct